# Log messages in Logstash JSON format from ActiveMQ

Tags: elasticsearch, activemq-classic, kibana, fluentd

I am running an ActiveMQ broker in a RedHat OpenShift cluster, with an EFK (ElasticSearch, Fluentd, Kibana) stack handling logging. In my java components I have configured my loggers to log in JSON format using the LogStash encoder so that they can be properly parsed, stored and displayed in Kibana and I'm looking to do the same for ActiveMQ.

In my Java components my logging configuration looks like and I expected to be able to do something similar for ActiveMQ:

```
<configuration>

    <appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LogstashEncoder" />
    </appender>
    <logger name="jsonLogger" additivity="false" level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
    </logger>

<root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
</root>
```

The ActiveMQ docs don't seem to mention any way of changing the logging appender: http://activemq.apache.org/how-do-i-change-the-logging.html

Has anyone managed to do this successfully before?